# how to selectively fill na values that uses less time for data points of 30,800

Tags: python, string, pandas, replace, fillna

I have a column with the name `home/away`. Now in this column entry are either `home` or `away` or in some cases `NaN`. I want to fill some of these `NaN` values based on another column which is `lat/lng`. What I want to do is check if the value for `lat/lng` is equal to `42.982923, -71.446094` and if this value corresponds to the `home/away` column which is `NaN`, I want to fill that `NaN` with `home`.

I've made code to do so, but it is taking way too much computing time since I have 30800 data points. So can anyone help me figure out some faster way to fill this conditional fill-`NaN` method? The code which I made consists of `for, if, else`.

Please help in figuring out a fast method.

```
for i in df[df['home/away'].isnull()].index:
    if df['lat/lng'][i] == '42.982923, -71.446094':
        df['home/away'][i] = 'home'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just filter on both conditions, like:

```
selection = (df['home/away'].isnull()) & (df['lat/lng'] == '42.982923, -71.446094')
df.loc[selection, 'home/away'] = 'home'
```

We here thus will set the values in "*bulk*", given that the `home/away` column is `NaN`, and the `lat/long` column is `'42.982923, -71.446094'`.